# How to call .hoverIntent on a element generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hoverintent

In my .js script I add a div that will hold a slickgrid, then I add other elements inside the grid, all when my js script loads.

```
var container = $('#container');
container.html('<div id="gridView"></div>');
```

then I want to add the hoverIntent library functionality to it so that a popover, triggered on hovering over a element, doesn't pop up unless I hold the hover for a little while (slower then instant)

My popover looks like this (it's inside a font awesome tag that's inside a slickgrid cell), so when I hover over this font awesome tag the popover appears. I want to use hoverIntent on it.

```
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="21657" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" onmouseover="tp.manageRollups.showCustomerIdList(21657);"></i> 21657</div>
```

I'm assuming I have to call something like

```js
$('#gridView').on('hoverIntent', 'i.fa.fa-plus-circle')
```

but I'm not sure! Any help would be appreciated.